# Compare Pre-Post tables in oracle sql without hardcoding

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I took a pre-image/post-image of the table before and after I ran a batchjob.

*PRE_TABLE*

```
id|Name  |Phone    |Score
1 |John  |145678   |10
2 |Ptr   |23456789 |20
3 |Sarah |34567890 |30
4 |Mary  |45678901 |40
```

*POST_TABLE*

```
id|Name  |Phone    |Score
1 |John  |12345678 |10
2 |Peter |23456789 |22
3 |Sarah |34567890 |33
4 |Mary  |45678901 |40
```

How do i compare and extract the modified fields and present them as follows:

*Desired OUTPUT*

```
id|modifiedColumn|modifiedVal|prevVal
1 |Phone         |12345678   |145678   
2 |Name          |Peter      |Ptr
2 |Score         |22         |20
3 |Score         |33         |30
```

---

So far, I can get the modified rows using

```
select * from POST_TABLE
minus select * from PRE_TABLE
```

which gives me

```
id|Name  |Phone    |Score
1 |John  |12345678 |10
2 |Peter |23456789 |22
3 |Sarah |34567890 |33
```

---

I am thinking of using All_tab_columns to iterate the fields in the table

```
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME ='PRE_TABLE';
```

---

I have written a partial pl-sql procedure, but got stuck when I wanted to compare the column names.

```
procedure diff
as
cursor POST_CUR is
(select * from Post_table minus select * from Pre_table);

cursor pre_CUR is
(select * from Pre_table);

cursor COLUMNS_CUR is
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME ='Post_table';

begin
  for R in post_CUR LOOP
      for p in pre_CUR LOOP
          if (R.id=P.id) then
              for F in COLUMNS_CUR LOOP
                     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('id:'||R.ID||'_'||F.COLUMN_NAME);
                  --compare f.column_name.. STUCK Here!! 
                  --if (R.[f.column_name] <>P.[f.column_name] )
                     --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('id:'||R.ID||'_'||F.COLUMN_NAME||'_'||R.[f.column_name]||'_'||P.[f.column_name]);
                  --end if;
              end LOOP;
          end if;
      end LOOP;
  end LOOP;

end DIFF;
```

How do I get my table results dynamically without hardcoding the table column names? I am open to use pl-sql or anything else that works.
TIA.

Comment: Take a look at a script I wrote to do this in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22727328/409172).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the results you are looking for using following SQL:

```
--phone
SELECT A.ID, 'Phone' As ModifiedColumn,
B.Phone As ModifiedVal,
A.Phone As PrevVal
FROM PRE_TABLE A
INNER JOIN POST_TABLE B ON A.ID = B.ID AND COALESCE(A.PHONE,'-') <> COALESCE(B.PHONE,'-')

--name
UNION ALL
SELECT A.ID, 'Name' As ModifiedColumn,
B.Phone As ModifiedVal,
A.Phone As PrevVal
FROM PRE_TABLE A
INNER JOIN POST_TABLE B ON A.ID = B.ID AND COALESCE(A.Name,'-') <> COALESCE(B.Name,'-')

--score
UNION ALL
SELECT A.ID, 'Score' As ModifiedColumn,
B.Phone As ModifiedVal,
A.Phone As PrevVal
FROM PRE_TABLE A
INNER JOIN POST_TABLE B ON A.ID = B.ID AND COALESCE(A.Score,'0') <> COALESCE(B.Score,'0')
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without hardcoding the column names? By maybe using "Select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME ='Post_table';" to get the column names?